# Qt5Cored.lib(Qt5Cored.dll) : module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: qt, jenkins, msbuild, cmake, qt5

I do all in Jenkins. 
I'm using CMake for configuring my project with Makefile Generator: Visual Studio 12. After this I have solution file - ***.sln. My next step is building project using MSBuild. I run it with command line arguments -/p:"VisualStudioVersion=12.0". While this step is prorocessing I get the message:

```
> Qt5Cored.lib(Qt5Cored.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

I tried to using Makefile Generator : Visual Studio 12 Win64 and there were more failures. After I also tried to run MSBuild with parameter `/p:"Platform=x64"` but it failed - `"Debug|x64"` is invalid.

I have Qt for x64 platform and my machine is x64 too. I also have right paths to Qt in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. I really have no idea what else to do:C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem: I install Qt for x86 and it works:))

Comment: So you haven't solved it at all, you've just given up.

Comment: No, this is a valid solution.  Not the only solution, but it works.

Comment: It results in a 32bit binary, but the platform is 64bit, this has not solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe @fr0st doesn't need a 64-bit binary.  Maybe they are new to this and thought they had to match their development environment rather than the target environment.  The question is about bit-ness mismatch, not about how to build 64-bit.

Comment: Really I notice that our build can't be gather for x64 because uses Qt x32. It was my mistake when I wanted to build it using Qt x64